# indent in html description

Tags: html, indentation

I am creating my webpage, using HTML5 (but possibly what I am asking has nothing to do with  5 spicificaly).
I am trying to have a indent there, like,

```
<ol>
  <li> <fontspec from css>title</fontspec from css> detail about title
  </li>
  <li>..</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

What I want is the "detail about title" should appear in the next line (I am using `br` for that), and will be intended; as

```
1. title
     detail about title
```

I can have the effect using space `&nbsp` , but then I have to remember all the number of space I am entering, for all the page. Is there any tag in html that will do these things for me?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your reply, indent is working, but as normal to `<p>`, this is not writing to the next line, but taking one line extra gap. Its now coming as:

```
1. title

   detail about title
```

**EDIT2**

Here is the snippet from actual page:

*In Html:*

```
<ol>
      <li>
      <item>title</item><p class="indent">details about title</p>
      </li>
</ol>
```

*in css:*

```
item{
  font-size :120%;
  color     :#096cdb;
  font-weight : bold;
}
.indent{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT as jukka's comment **
I have realized theat item is not html tag. w3c validator is giving error, though chrome is rendering it as my intention. I tried to put h4 instead of item, but it is also taking space of next line. So, what is the way out?

**EDIT:**

solved the job.

I have defined in css:

```
dt.item{
  font-size :120%;
  color     :#096cdb;
  font-weight : bold;
}
```

and then did:

```
  <li>
  <dl>
<dt class="item">title</dt>
<dd>details about title</dd>
  </dl>
  </li>
```

This has the output I am looking for, and is also validated by w3c.

Comment: `<fontspec from css>` is not an HTML tag. Please post actual HTML markup, and add explanations in prose if needed.

Comment: `<item>` isn’t HTML either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. You could use definition list;

```
    <ol>
        <li>
            <dl>
                <dt><fontspec from css>title</fontspec from css></dt>
                <dd>detail about title</dd>
            <dl>  
        </li>
        <li>..</li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the real markup has something like

```
<li> <span class=title>title</span> detail about title</li>
```

and, for definiteness, that you wish to apply the same styling principle to all `li` elements, you can make the `span` element rendered as a block (causing line break after it) and set a negative first-line indent (`text-indent` property) and the corresponding positive left padding on the `li` elements. This means that in `li` elements, any lines except the first one will be indented by the amount you set. In the following example, the amount equals the size of the font:

```
<style>
.title { display: block; }
li { text-indent: -1em; padding-left: 1em; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's give it a class.

```
<p class="indent">detail about title</p>
```

Afterwards, we'll use CSS to set a margin to the left of the text.

```
.indent {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

That should give you an indent. Adjust accordingly :)

Note that by using a paragraph element, there's no need for a line break anymore.